# The system cannot find the file specified in android studio?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a new sample app in Android Studio 2.0. When I try to Run or debug it shows a compile time error like,

Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Android Studio\newapp\app\libs\core.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)

I had tried by giving path JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45 and
Sync project with gradle.

This is My Gradle

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
...
}

dependencies {

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1-alpha2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'

compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.6'
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
compile files('libs/core.jar')
```

}

Even after that I cant find any solution.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> libs\core.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)

Seems like an obvious error to me...

Remove this line. You don't need it

```
compile files('libs/core.jar')
```

You **could** add a `core.jar` file into the libs folder, but you still wouldn't need that line since you are already compiling it

Also, pick only one version, please. You don't need to add them multiple times

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1-alpha2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
```

Same for these

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

Comment: Where can I remove it?

Comment: You only showed one file in your question, so where do you think?